# Companies searching for tutors to teach its employees or their employees?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Our platform is designed to pair students (and/or their parents), searching for tutors, with tutors, for online and offline one-to-one or group lessons, and for Companies searching for tutors to teach **its** employees (or **their** employees)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109926/discussion-on-question-by-papakota-companies-searching-for-tutors-to-teach-its-e).